# Show / hide divs between 2 divs between two pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have 6 divs, 2 have contents in them and they are either hidden or visible depending on which of the 2 'hide' and  2'show' divs are clicked, please look at the Fiddle to see what I mean.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lycrest15/GkTa7/1/)

page1.html

```
<div id="show-politics" class="topics">show</div>
<div id="show-technology" class="topics">show</div>
```

page2.html

```
<div id="hide-politics" class="topics">hide</div>
<div id="rss-feeds" class="me">contents</div>

<div id="hide-technology" class="topics">hide</div>
<div id="rss-feeds2" class="me">contents</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
        $('#hide-politics').click(function(e) {
            localStorage.setItem('subscribed', true);
            $('#rss-feeds,#hide-politics').hide();
            $('#hide-politics').hide();
            $('#show-politics').show();
        });
        $('#show-politics').click(function(e) {
            localStorage.setItem('subscribed', true);
            localStorage.clear();
            $('#rss-feeds,#hide-politics').show();
            $('#show-politics').hide();
        });
        var is_subscribed = localStorage.getItem('subscribed');
        if (is_subscribed) {
            console.log('localStorage');
            $('#rss-feeds,#hide-politics').hide();
        }
        if (!is_subscribed) {
            console.log('no localStorage');
            $('#rss-feeds').show();
            $('#show-politics').hide();
        }
    }
});

$(document).ready(function($) {
    if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
        $('#hide-technology').click(function(e) {
            localStorage.setItem('subscribed2', true);
            $('#rss-feeds2,#hide-technology').hide();
            $('#hide-technology').hide();
            $('#show-technology').show();
        });
        $('#show-technology').click(function(e) {
            localStorage.setItem('subscribed2', true);
            localStorage.clear();
            $('#rss-feeds2,#hide-technology').show();
            $('#show-technology').hide();
        });
        var is_subscribed2 = localStorage.getItem('subscribed2');
        if (is_subscribed2) {
            console.log('localStorage');
            $('#rss-feeds2,#hide-technology').hide();
        }
        if (!is_subscribed2) {
            console.log('no localStorage');
            $('#rss-feeds2').show();
            $('#show-technology').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

I need the 'show' divs to be on another page from the 'hide' divs and the contents divs, which are on the same page, this works to some extent, the only problem is that, I cannot make ONLY 1 div visible when the 'show' divs are on another page, when I click 1 'show' div, all the hidden divs become visible instead of just the one, but when they are on the same page, they behave the way they are supposed to, like in the fiddle,

Can you take a look at my code and see if there is a way i can make it behave the same way in the fiddle when on separate pages?

it uses modenizr local storage

Comment: What do you mean by `I need the 'show' divs to be on another page`?  You can't just send a div to another page.

Comment: @Anonymous he's using localStorage to communicate between the two pages on the same domain.

Comment: i mean that (div id="show-technology") and (div id="show-politics") are not on the same page as all the other divs as i show above, i click them on a different page and because of local storage, they affect the divs on the other page, just, not in the way i want

Comment: it's necessary because of the nature of the architecture of my app

Comment: Yea, I realized that, which is why I edited the comment.

Comment: Have you thought about using javascript cookies? That's how you can get data to cross multiple pages on the front end. The only other option is to use ajax and dynamically reload the content and then callback a function to hide the newly generated content that shoul dbe hidden.

Comment: @JemiloII thanks for that, i'm looking into how I can go about that.